# ngModel two way binding for nested *ngFor in angular

Tags: html, angular

My JSON looks like:

```
 "assets" : [ 
        {
            "resourceName" : "keyboard",
            "characteristics" : {
                "serialNo" : "abc123",
                "brand" : "DELL"
            }
        }, 
        {
            "resourceName" : "Domain Account"
        }
    ]
```

I am performing two way binding for displaying serialNo and brand values in html form as an input. Here's my html input code

```html
<table border="0">
   <tr *ngFor="let r of assets; let i=index">
          <td>{{r.resourceName | uppercase}} :</td>
          <td *ngFor="let key of r.characteristics | keys;let in=index; trackBy:keys" >
   {{key | uppercase}}:
   <input name="r.characteristics[key]" value="r.characteristics[key]" [(ngModel)]="r.characteristics[key]">&nbsp;&nbsp;
             </td>
            </tr>
     </table>
```

In my form, for both the input fields, I am getting the value as DELL which is the value of brand. I want "abc123" to be displayed in serialNo field and DELL in brand field. Please refer to the [plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/6LM20uU26NQRYNenRo8c?p=preview) for exact problem description.Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is your exact question?

Comment: please show relevant code about `keys` Pipe you are currently using.

Comment: What is your question? Do you want this input to both view/change value of `r.characteristics[key]`?

Comment: yes @SharikovVladislav , that's what I want.

Comment: stop writing angular in a way of angular js please... https://angular.io/guide/dynamic-form

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I don't see in your snippet the pipe `keys`, it should be as the following:

```
@Pipe({ name: 'keys',  pure: false })

export class KeysPipe implements PipeTransform {
    transform(value: any, args: any[] = null): any {
        return Object.keys(value)
    }
}
```

Also, the name attribute should be set correctly:

**HTML:**

```
  <input name="someName[i]" [(ngModel)]="r.characteristics[key]">
```

[**plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/wTfkxGk6e9XmLQbQuTD0?p=preview)

Comment: its not working when inside the form tag. please see the plunker.https://plnkr.co/edit/6LM20uU26NQRYNenRo8c?p=preview

Comment: post your trackBy function (named 'keys') too pls... if there is one. To my knowledge, trackBy will only work with a function –

Comment: Problem was in the name attribute  of the input tag. There was no interpolation used in name.